# For which $x$ values this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1n \cos^2(nx)$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have tried using Dirichlet's Test with $\cos^2nx = \dfrac{1+\cos(2nx)}{2} = \frac 12 + \dfrac{\cos(2nx)}{2}$, this show that I can't bound the partial sums.

What another test may I apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument shows that the series diverges for all $x$, since it is the sum of a divergentes series and a convergente series.

Comment: Which is the convergent one?

Comment: Dirichlet's criterion shows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(2nx)/n$ converges if $x\ne2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.